# crontab bash script not running

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I updated the script with the absolute paths.  Also here is my current cronjob entry.

I went and fixed the ssh key issue so I know it works know, but might still need to tell rsync what key to use.

The script runs fine when called manually by user.  It looks like not even the rm commands are being executed by the cron job.

UPDATE

I updated my script but basically its the same as the one below.  Below I have a new cron time and added an error output.

I get nothing.  It looks like the script doesn't even run.

crontab -e

35 0 * * * /bin/bash /x/y/z/s/script.sh 2>1 > /tmp/tc.log

```
#!/bin/bash
# Clean up
/bin/rm -rf /z/y/z/a/b/current/*
cd /z/y/z/a/to/
/bin/rm -rf ?s??/D????
cd /z/y/z/s/

# Find the latest file
FILE=`/usr/bin/ssh user@server /bin/ls -ht /x/y/z/t/a/ | /usr/bin/head -n 1`

# Copy over the latest archive and place it in the proper directory
/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e /urs/bin/ssh user@server:"/x/y/z/t/a/$FILE" /x/y/z/t/a/

# Unzip the zip file and place it in the proper directory
/usr/bin/unzip -o /x/y/z/t/a/$FILE -d /x/y/z/t/a/current/

# Run Dev's script
cd /x/y/z/t/
./old.py a/current/ t/ 5
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to use absolute paths for commands

Comment: I have tried bash /x/y/z/s/old.py or /x/y/z/s/./old.py, but still didn't work

Comment: So is the problem getting the script to run, or a problem with the script when its running? If the script doesn't run, can you post the crontab entry you have.

Comment: @JDoe Use absolute paths for commands, for example `/usr/bin/unzip`. You can know them by using `which unzip`.

Comment: Any output from the script should be emailed to you. If it's getting an error, you should see that in the email.

Comment: cd isn't in /bin, use it like this: cd /z/y/z/a/to/. rsync and unzip are usually in /usr/bin.

Comment: Your crontab entry is wrong. `10 17 * * * /x/y/z/s/./old.py` is just trying to run the last line in the whole script. You need to run the whole script in cron, not just the last line. Your crontab should be `10 17 * * * /x/y/z/s/path/to/script` and put a shebang on that script.

Comment: Can you confirm if the first 5 lines are being executed? Also, is the crontab's user granted with permissions to execute those commands (`rm`)

Comment: It doesn't look like the first few lines are being execute, but I'll try and comment out the other and try them solely.  How do I see if the crontab user has permission?

Comment: I checked and I didn't see the rm command running

Comment: Add the error log entry `10 22 * * * /bin/bash /x/y/z/s/path/to/script 2>1 > /dir/for/error/log` and show file `log`

Comment: I didn't get a chance to do it today, but will try tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I'm use to working in cst and the server was in gmt time.

Thanks everybody for the help.